# how to use vbulletin variable from postbit on custom template

Tags: php, vbulletin

I have vbulletin 4 forum and I'v installed vbadvanced CMPS.

Now I would like to customize NEWS module and what I need is to use variables from **postbit** template and call it on **adv_portal_newsbits** template...how can I do that?

There is news.php file which controls NEWS module and adv_portal_newsbits template...I did some search and it looks to me that I need to register variables from postbit template inside news.php file...or maybe I'm wrong?

If this is true, how can I register variables that I need? 
(I need post title, image from first post and text)

Answer (score 0):

Postbit template has all the info for one thread, in your case it sounds like you should get the threadbit info. What you will need to do is take a look at the forumdisplay.php, look at how it gets the threadbit.
Then in your news.php, you want do something like this:

```
require_once(DIR . '/includes/functions_forumdisplay.php');
$threads = $db->query_read_slave (sql query, depends on what you need);
$threadbits;
while ($thread = $db->fetch_array($threads)) {
  // this method is from the functions_forumdisplay.php
  $threadbits .= process_thread_array($thread);
}
$templater = vB_Template::create('adv_portal_newsbits');
$templater->register('threadbits', $threadbits);
print_output($templater->render());
```

Now in your adv_portal_newsbits template, you can just call {vb:raw threadbits}. Note the threadbits is an array contains all the thread that fit your query, but you can use {vb:each}